# Why is compactness required for Brunn-Minkowski theorem?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Brunn-Minkowski theorem reads as follows:

Consider two nonempty compact sets $A, B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Then the following inequality holds

$$
[M(A+B)]^{\frac{1}{n}} \geq [M(A)]^{\frac{1}{n}} + [M(B)]^{\frac{1}{n}}
$$

where $M$ denotes the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I was wondering the rationale behind the hypothesis of copactness for $A$ and $B$. I couldn't really find it by myself in the proof. Even an intuitive explanation, if it exists, would suffice.

Comment: I think it is to guarantee that the measures are finite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is true if $A+B$ is measurable, this is the critical part in the assumption. If $A,B$ are compact, then so is $A+B$ and therefore measureable.

Here is a proof for the theorem with the assumption of $A+B$ to be measurable using the statement for compact $A,B$:

For arbitrary $\tilde A,\tilde B$ compact with $\tilde A\subset A$ and $\tilde B\subset B$ it follows $M(\tilde A)^\frac{1}{n}+M(\tilde B)^\frac{1}{n} \leq M(\tilde A+\tilde B)^\frac{1}{n} \leq M(A+B)^\frac{1}{n}$.

By regularity of Lebesgue measure we obtain the statement for $A,B$ by taking suprema over all such $\tilde A,\tilde B$.

Comment: A nice [question on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/19471/is-the-sum-of-2-lebesgue-measurable-sets-measurable) which complement your answer (+1).

Comment: This makes perfectly sense. And I guess $A+B$ is guaranteed to be compact as it is the continuous image (under the addition operation) of $A \times B$, which is compact?

Comment: Yes, this is the right argument. Thanks for the link, Arctic Char. A nice question indeed.